# In what circumstances might using biases in a neural network not be beneficial?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am currently looking through Michael Nielsen's ebook [Neural Networks and Deep Learning](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/) and have run the code found at the end of chapter 1 which trains a neural network to recognize hand-written digits (with a slight modification to make the backpropagation algorithm over a mini-batch matrix-based).

However, having run this code and achieving a classification accuracy of just under 94%, I decided to remove the use of biases from the network. After re-training the modified network, I found no difference in classification accuracy!

**NB:** The output layer of this network contains ten neurons; if the ith of these neurons has the highest activation then the input is classified as being the digit i.

This got me wondering *why* it is necessary to use biases in a neural network, rather than just weights, and what differentiates between a task where biases will improve the performance of a network and a task where they will not?

My code can be found here: https://github.com/pipthagoras/neural-network-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Biases are used to account for the fact that your underlying data might not be centered. It is clearer to see in the case of a linear regression.

[image]

If you do a regression without an intercept (or bias), you are forcing the underlying model to pass through the origin, which will result in a poor model if the underlying data is not centered (for example if the true generating process is Y=3000). If, on the other hand, your data is centered or close to centered, then eliminating bias is good, since you won't introduce a term that is, in fact, independent to your predictive variable (it's like selecting a simpler model, which will tend to generalize better PROVIDED that it actually reflects the underlying data).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would you say that regression was necessarily comparable to how a neural network works though? If so, then what does it mean for data (such as handwritten digits) to be centered in the context of a neural network?

Comment: In the case of classification the better analogy is logistic regression (since it is the case of a cross-entropy loss without hidden layers and a softmax activation). If you don't include an intercept in logistic regression, your model assumes that all of your classes are equally distributed i,e P(Y=0)=P(Y=1).... P(Y=9)=0.1

Comment: Ah, so maybe that explains why using biases didn't improve the performance of the digit-classification program, since the digits 0-9 all occur with equal probability?

Comment: Maybe, but remember that you can add bias in intermediate layers as well. As I said before, the overall effect is restricting your model to a subfamily that assumes some type of symmetry.